# jQuery Reference First Column in HTML Table

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a table where all of the cells are INPUT tags. I have a function which looks for the first **input** cell and replaces it with it's value. So this:

```
<tr id="row_0" class="datarow">
    <td><input class="tabcell" value="Injuries"></td>
    <td><input class="tabcell" value="01"></td>
```

becomes this:

```
<tr id="row_0" class="datarow">
    <td>Injuries</td>
    <td><input class="tabcell" value="01"></td>
```

Here is the first part of the function:

```
function setRowLabels() {

    var row = [];
    $('.dataRow').each(function(i) {
        row.push($('td input:eq(0)', this).val() + ' -> ');
        $('td input:eq(0)', this).replaceWith($('td input:eq(0)', this).val());
        $('td input:gt(0)', this).each(function(e) {
    etcetera
```

But when the page reloads, the first column is not an input type, so it changes the second column to text too!

Can I tell it to only change the first column, no matter what the type is? I tried 
     `$('td:eq(0)', this).replaceWith($('td:eq(0)', this).val());`

but it does not work.

Any suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your version, you were selecting the `td` instead of the `input`.

```
  // Selects the first td in the row
$('td:eq(0)', this).replaceWith($('td:eq(0)', this).val());
```

Try this:

```
  // Selects the input of the first td in the row
$('td:eq(0) input', this).replaceWith($('td:eq(0) input', this).val());
```

Comment: When I first read your response I thought that you had typed in exactly what I had tried the first time. After re-reading, I see that you changed 
'td input:eq(0)' 
 to 'td:eq(0) input'<br />

And it worked!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the CSS td:nth-child Pseudo-class.

http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/Test/CSS3/Selectors/current/html/full/flat/css3-modsel-28b.html

Comment: Also, not sure if you caught this but you have "datarow" as your tr's class attribute value, and "dataRow" as the value in your JQuery function.

Comment: Oops, typo. They are both dataRow.

Comment: The CSS td:nth-child Pseudo-class is now bookmarked! Pretty bright colours though...